# Bindestriche in Komposita mit Eigennamen und anderen Substantiven

Tags: person-names, scientific-language, hyphenation

In der Physik ist es üblich Konzepte, Phänomene und Gleichungen nach ihren Entdeckern oder Entdeckerinnen zu benennen. Meist kommen hierbei Bindestriche zwischen den Namensgebenden und dem Konzept zum Einsatz. Beispielhaft führe ich hier die Schreibweise in der deutschen Wikipedia an.

- [Wick-Rotation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick-Rotation)
- [Bloch-Gleichungen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch-Gleichungen)
- [Lorentz-Transformation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz-Transformation)
- [Fermi-Dirac-Statisik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi-Dirac-Statistik)

Bei anderen Begriffen jedoch, wird der Bindestrich unterlassen und das Wort zusammengeschrieben. Speziell fallen mir hier die mit Herrn Larmor assozierten Wörter auf.

- [Larmorfrequenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmorpr%C3%A4zession)
- [Larmorpräzession](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmorpr%C3%A4zession)

Diese Schreibweise ist in der einschlägigen Literatur und zumindest an meiner Universität vorherschend. Allerdings gibt es auch Gegenbeispiele. So schreibt das Spektrum Lexikon der Physik "[Larmor-Präzession](http://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/larmor-praezession/8786)".

Ein weiteres Beispiel wäre "Fermi-Verteilung" in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi-Dirac-Statistik) und [Spektrum](http://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/fermi-verteilung/4904) und "Fermiverteilung" sowie gemischte Benutzung beim [Chemie.de-Lexikon](http://www.chemie.de/lexikon/Fermiverteilung.html) und einer (zugegebenermaßen wenig vertrauenserweckenden) [Seite](http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/mw2_ge/kap_2/backbone/r2_3_2.html) der Uni Kiel. Google Trends [zeigt](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=DE&q=Fermiverteilung,Fermi-Verteilung), dass "Fermiverteilung" wesentlich populärer sei, möglicherweise liegt das jedoch daran, dass es einfacher zu Tippen ist.

Da die meisten Begriffe mit Bindestrich geschrieben werden, und es bei Begriffen mit mehreren Namen ("Fermi-Dirac-Statistik", "Wigner-Eckard-Theorem") meiner Meinung nach auch nicht anders geht, würde ich stark für den Bindestrich argumentieren. Gibt es eine einheitliche Regelung? Sollte man sich in dem Fall gegen die Konvention verhalten? Weder dem Wikipediaartikel zu "[Leerzeichen in Komposita](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita)" noch "[Durchkopplung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung)" konnte ich die richtige Antwort entnehmen.

Comment: Zieht man den Duden (und hier hilfsweise die Straßennamen) zu Rate, so sagt er, dass Namen mit mehrteiligen Namen mit Bindestrich geschrieben werden (Regel 162, Pkt. 3). Straßennamen mit nur einem Namen werden zusammengeschrieben (Beethovenstraße). Regel 21 ff. zu Bindestrichen sagt, man **kann** ihn zur Verdeutlichung setzen. Also **muss es** "Fermi-Dirac-Statistik" sein, **kann** aber "Larmor-Präzession" oder "Larmorpräzession" sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Rechtschreibrat läßt sich intensiv über diesen Schverhalt in [§46-§52](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf) aus und widmet dem Thema einige Seiten. Hier steht grundsätzlich, dass Zusammensetzungen, die als zweiten Bestandteil einen Eigennamen enthalten, und mehrteilige Zusammensetzungen mit Eigennamen mit Bindestrich geschrieben werden sollen.

Als einzige Ausnahme davon werden Zusammensetzungen mit Eigennamen, die eine *Gattungsbezeichnung* ergeben, genannt: *Heulsuse*, *Meckerfritze*, *Gänseliesel*. Das trifft hier aber wohl nicht zu.

§51 sagt, man *kann* einen Bindestrich setzen, wenn Zusammensetzungen als ersten Bestandteil einen (einzelnen) Eigennamen haben, der besonders hervorgehoben werden soll, oder wenn der zweite Bestandteil bereits eine Zusammensetzung ist.

Nach diesen Regeln ist also sowohl *Fermi-Verteilung* (unter der Annahme, das *Fermi* besonders hervorgehoben werden soll) als auch *Fermiverteilung* richtig. <s>*Fermi-Diracstatistik*</s> <s>*Mathematikgauss*</s> und <s>*Geigermüllerzähler*</s> wäre in jedem Fall falsch.

Answer (score 1):

Ich meine, diese Frage sollte weniger durch Rückgriff auf **Orthographen-Regelwerke** beantwortet werden (obwohl auch diese natürlich wertvoll und wichtig sind) sondern eher aus der Ecke der guten **Schriftsetzer-Praxis**. Also nicht "Was ist richtig?" sondern: Wie würde es eine gute Zeitung, ein guter **Schulbuch- oder Wissenschaftsverlag**, eine gute **Lexikonredaktion** machen?

Es gibt hier einige Faktoren zu bedenken.

Ist die Zusammensetzung bereits etabliert? **'Geigerzähler'** wäre etabliert. Niemand (jedenfalls niemand aus der professionellen Setzerei) würde hier Geiger-Zähler schreiben.

Ergäbe sich aus Mehrfachzusammensetzungen ein Wort zu lang für das Auge? 'Mehrfachzusammensetzungsvermeidung' wäre zu lang (das Auge erfasst, sagen wir, 40-50 Buchstaben in einer einheitlichen Gestalt, und irgendwann wird's halt zu viel). Also neigen wir zur **Mehrfachzusammensetzungs-Vermeidung**. Schlichtweg aus Rücksicht auf den Leser.

Eine Unsitte, die sich verbreitet, ist es, ganz auf Bindestrich oder Zusammenschreibung zu verzichten. "... kam es in der Bodo Müller Straße zu einem Auffahrunfall..." Schlecht! Nach guter deutscher Schriftsatztradition bindet man die Wörter hier zusammen zur **Bodo-Müller-Straße**. Der Potsdamer Platz oder auch die **Ausgburger Allee** bleiben in Einzelwörtern, da der vordere Teil als Adjektiv verstanden wird, wenn auch großgeschrieben. Der Mexiko-Platz in Wien jedoch braucht einen Bindestrich. Wenn nicht sowieso 'Mexikoplatz' üblich ist. Das weiß ich nicht. Mehr und mehr Firmen, doch sogar auch Universitäten gehen mittlerweile dazu über, Bindestriche in ihrem Namen wegzulassen. So nennt sich dann 'Ludwig Maximilians Universität', was nach guter Tradition **Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität** heißen müsste. Dies ist sicherlich vom Englischen übernommen.

Sehr konsequent und sprachtraditionell wendet den Bindestrich dagegen sogar heute noch die **Ada-und-Theodor-Lessing-Volkshochschule Hannover** an, die dies so auch auf ihrem Briefpapier benützt und sich dem coolen Anglizieren somit wiedersetzt. An dieser Stelle darum eine Danksagung (ohne Bindestrich) sowie den Ausdruck unserer Hochachtung (auch ohne) an diese Hohepriesterin (ohne) des **Schriftkulturbestands**. Oder Schriftkultur-Bestands?

Comment: Ich kann leider deiner Argumentation im ersten Absatz nicht ganz folgen: Willst du uns sagen, dass eine *gute Zeitung* oder *eine Lexikon-Redaktion* (Gott bewahre!) den Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung nicht folgen muss und auch nicht folgt?